# vectors multiple and parallel rule.

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, scalar-fields

if two vectors such as **AB** and **CD** are parallel then **AB**/**CD** = m . where "m" is a scalar multiple. then is it necessary that the "m" should belong to R\0..? and if those vectors are not parallel then CAN'T one be expressed as another's scalar multiple?

Answer (score 0):

two vectors are parallel if there exist a real constant $\alpha$ such that $$AB=\alpha CD$$

Comment: well i also mentioned that sir but what if one vector is not parallel to other then can't they have such constant?